# java.lang.NullPointerException erro

Tags: java, hibernate

Boas , estou a  tentar usar o session = sessionFactory.openSession(); para ir buscar objetos na BD e da-me o seguinte erro.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.ual.aas.lab01.controllers.DAO.getSession(DAO.java:18)
    at org.ual.aas.lab01.controllers.TaskListController.getLists(TaskListController.java:17)
    at org.ual.aas.lab01.controllers.PersistenceController.main(PersistenceController.java:96)
*texto grifado*

```
 public static Session getSession() {
            Session session = (Session) DAO.session.get();

            if (session == null) {
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                DAO.session.set(session);
            }

            return session;
        }

        protected void begin() {
            getSession().beginTransaction();
        }

        protected void commit() {
            getSession().getTransaction().commit();
        }

        protected void rollback() {
            try {
                getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            } catch( HibernateException e ) {
                System.out.println("Não foi possível fazer rollback da transação");
            }

            try {
                getSession().close();
            } catch( HibernateException e ) {
                System.out.println("Não foi possível fazer fechar a sessão");
            }

            DAO.session.set(null);
        }

        public static void close() {
            getSession().close();
            DAO.session.set(null);
        }


        private static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();

        static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
            final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
             .configure("resource/hibernate.cfg.xml")
             .build();
}
```

```
//Gera lista de listas
    public static TaskList  getLists(TaskList List)  {  

        DAO.getSession().beginTransaction();
        List resultado = DAO.getSession().createQuery("from TaskList").list();

        for(TaskList list : (List<TaskList>)resultado) {
             System.out.println(list.getName());        
        System.out.println(List.getName());
        }

        return null;
```

Comment: Você está setando nulo em vários lugares do seu código.

Comment: Tente não utilizar `null` no seu código. Eu percebo que você faz `DAO.session.set(null);` mas não achei nenhum lugar onde você coloca o valor nesse object. Então claramente o NullPointException vai acontecer. Uma outra sugestão é não utilizar um objeto seu para gerenciar a sessão, você o chama de DAO. Melhor usar o próprio `getSession()` que você tem.